# Does Euclid book I proposition 2 have a purpose?

Tags: logic, euclidean-geometry

According to
[Joyce](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookI/propI2.html)'
commentary, 
proposition 2 is *only* used in proposition 3 of Euclid's *Elements*, book I.

As Euclid states himself 
([I-3](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookI/propI3.html), 
the length of the shorter line is measured 
(as the radius of a circle) 
directly on the longer line 
(by letting the center of the circle reside on an extremity of the longer line).
The incremental (deductive) chain of 
definitions, common notions, constructions and propositions seems thus
broken by introducing a ''useless'' statement, namely I-2.
- Or am I looking for the meaning of proposition I-2 in the wrong place?

A related question would be: Does the proposition in case *need* a purpose?

Comment: Have you heard of lemmas?

Comment: Certainly, @Kenny Lau. But as far as I am informed, lemmas are stepping stones _to something bigger_, and that is exactly what puzzles me - **a lemma leading nowhere**?

Comment: well, I.3 is *something bigger* than I.2?

Comment: According to the mentioned commentary, proposition I-2 is _used in_ prop. I-3, so in that respect, yes I-3 **is** bigger than I-3.

Comment: @Engelsmann: Can you clarify? You've both stated that the proposition leads to I-3 and that it leads nowhere. These are inconsistent statements.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnit Agreed that is inconsistent. I quoted _a commentary_ that I-2 leads to I-3. But I argue that one has no need to use I-2 when construcing I-3. Thus, my question comes down to this: **Problems of what nature can I-2 solve for us**? Or to this, more archivist question: _For what later Euclidean propositions is I-2 necessary?_

Comment: This statement is equivalent to the [axiom of segment construction](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Axiom:Axiom_of_Segment_Construction).

Comment: @Aretino: But the axiom sits in another axiomatical system. Thus, we have analogy but can a student of _Euclid_ use the _Tarski_-axiom you mention?

Comment: Don't be mislead by the abstract notation chosen by Wikipedia: that axiom can be found in almost every elementary geometry textbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement is equivalent to the [axiom of segment construction](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Axiom:Axiom_of_Segment_Construction) of modern textbooks. It is very important because it is needed to define the sum and difference of two segments.

EDIT.

Here's for instance the axiom (11.3 a.), as given in the textbook I'm using for first year high-school.

[image]

EDIT 2.

Some years ago a very interesting article appeared on The Mathematical Intelligencer (Vol. 15 N. 3): "A new look at Euclid's Second Proposition", by G. Toussaint. I think you will find there the ultimate answer to your doubts.

Comment: Can you point me to any such modern (geometry) textbook using axioms?

Comment: I teach in Italy and could give you plenty of examples of Italian high school textbooks, if you are interested. But I know nothing of American or English textbooks.

Comment: I teach in Denmark (K12 - gymnasium), Italian textbook titles will do just fine!

Comment: Here's for instance the one I use (K9): http://www.mondadoristore.it/matematica-colori-Ediz-blu-Leonardo-Sasso/eai978884941934/

Comment: The illustration helps a lot. In Denmark, the educational authorities have acquired a considerable fear of stringent reasoning. Instead authorities have developed a strong sympathy for computerized algebra systems (CAS) and the like. Thus, it is educational to a Danish mathematics teacher to see material from other school systems.

Comment: I shall look into [the Toussaint reference](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF03024252), too.

Comment: The Toussaint reference: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2668530_A_New_Look_At_Euclid%27s_Second_Proposition

Answer (score 1):

I think that this proposition is interesting by itself. It tells us that, using Euclidian tools only, we can draw equilateral triangles given one of its sides. The natural question now is: “Which regular polygons can I draw using compass and straightege only?” And you know where that question led us, don't you?

---

**Note:** Thanks to a comment, I realized that what I wrote is actually about proposition I.1, not I.2. Proposition I.2 tells us that we can transfer distances from a region of the plane to another one. One might think that this could be done using the compass alone (simply by not closing it), but Euclid actually never mentions compass (or straightedge); he just mentions the possibility of drawing line segments and circles. So, he needs to explain how is it possible, using these tools alone, to transfer distances.

Comment: Absolutely, I-2 is interesting in its own right, but I would like to follow any deductive chain of logic, I can find to progressively build problem solving skills and geometrical understanding. If you are referring to the critique of _proposition 1_ that no Euclidean axiom stated two circles with centres on each others discs intersect led to Hilbert building a thouroughly axiomatical geometry, that would be the proposition 1, not proposition 2, which I ask about. Otherwise, I would certainly need a hint!

Comment: Your edit of my tags moves focus away from the logic, IMHO. I posted here, not in [HSM.SE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) for that reason, and have no intend of historical research in my question.

Comment: @Engelsmann You always have the rollback option. I cannot force you to accept an edition.

Comment: In that case, I see it reasonable to roll back.

Comment: @Engelsmann Of course. And I shall not revert the edition.

Comment: You mentioned a "natural" question that _I-2_ leads to. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Engelsmann It's the one I mentioned: “Which regular polygons can I draw using compass and straightege only?”

Comment: But I do not know, where that question led us!

Comment: @Engelsmann Gauss asserted in 1801 that a polynomial with $n$ sides ($n>2$) can be drawn with Euclidean tools only if and only if $n$ is the product of a power of $2$ with the product of distinct Fermat primes, but he only proved the “if” part. The “only if” was proved by Pierre Wantzel in 1837.

Comment: I think this proposition has nothing to do with the construction of an equilateral triangle: that is the subject of Prop. 1.

Comment: @Aretino You are right. My mistake.

Comment: @Aretino  I've edited my answer..

Comment: Your edited answer very much clarifies my wondering.

Comment: @Engelsmann I'm glad I could help.